# Store active item in an array

Tags: design-patterns, database-design, nosql

In a NoSQL database (MongoDB), I need to store a list of `creditcards` for a `user` and to keep track of which one is `active`.

I came across 3 patterns:

#### #1 Keep the `active` property in the `Creditcard` schema

```
User
| _id: String
| creditcards: [Creditcard]
| ...

Creditcard
| _id: String
| active: Boolean
| ...
```

#### #2 Keep the reference of the active `Creditcard` in the `User`'s schema

```
User
| _id: String
| creditcards: [Creditcard]
| activeCreditcard: Creditcard
| ...

Creditcard
| _id: String
| ...
```

#### #3 Store a list of `creditcard` and `active` objects in the `User`'s schema

```
User
| _id: String
| creditcards: [{ creditcard: Creditcard, active: Boolean }]
| ...

Creditcard
| _id: String
| ...
```

I started to implement the first one but when I needed to update the `creditcards` and which one was active, I wasn't sure that this was the best pattern.

Hence, I tried to find different solutions but I can't choose.
Any recommendations?

Comment: Which one most effectively meets your specific requirements?  Note that [patterns are not building blocks](http://the-whiteboard.github.io/2016/09/02/patterns.html).  See also [When can a design pattern make your software worse?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1820106/when-can-a-design-pattern-make-your-software-worse)

Comment: I don't have very specific requirements, I just need to keep the Creditcard schema apart. Thanks for the links!

Answer (score 1):

The first one looks too relational to me for MongoDB. I know that's not a sin, but it looks like it is for an RDBMS.  For a document database I would keep it all as one document and simply mark one as active.  It is like #2, but I don't know what that second CreditCard document does.

```
-------------------
 key               
 ------------------
 _id               
 customer_id       
 credit_card       
 active  



db.customer_card.insert({customer_id: "AFB123", credit_card: 1234567812347890, active:true} )

db.customer_card.find({customer_id: {$eq: "AFB123"}, active:{$eq: true})
or
db.customer_card.find({customer_id: "AFB123", active:true})
```

You will have to test the commands.  I could not test them.

Comment: The `Creditcard` schema is shared with another collection so I need to keep it as a separate schema.

Comment: I didn't think MongoDB had a schema, per se.

Comment: I don't understand, what you described is like #1?

Comment: No.  I put it all in one.

Comment: @Kerumen I'm saying I'd duplicate data.

Comment: I'm using mongoose

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50896/discussion-between-kerumen-and-johnny).